# Using existing fields as objectId in mongodb to create REST api with node and express?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, express, restful-url

My JSON file is:

```
 [
   {'name': name,
    'birthday': birthday,
    'telephone': telephone,
    'details': details},
   ....
 ]
```

My application will be able to accept `name`, `birthday` and `telephone` values, and these three values combined are going to be unique for each entity. I am hoping to retrieve an entity based on these three values, say http://localhost:8000/name?=mary&birthday?=19880902&telephone?=2234324567 will return the json object of Mary.

I am looking at the examples available on using mongodb and nodejs, most of them suggest creating a completely new `_id` field using `new BSON.ObjectID(id)` and do something similar to `app.get('/users/:id', users.findById)` to find the id. Is it possible not to create a separate id field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a callback with the `(req, res)` parameters. See [here](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.get):

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  var findCursor = Users.find({ 
    "name": req.query.name, 
    "birthday": req.query.birthday,  
    "telephone": req.query.telephone 
  });
  cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
    if (err) console.log("Oh no!");
    if (doc != null) {
      // Do stuff
      res.send('GET request to user page?');
    }
  } 
});
```